# Shouldn't Astarte be under Kojou's control?

Tags: strike-the-blood

It was stated by Rudolph that Astarte had only two more weeks to live, because of the strain Rhododactylos familiar was putting on her body/soul/mana pool/whatever.

After defeating Rudolph, Kojou bites her

[image: Kojou bit Astarte]

and says that he would put the familiar under his control, so her lifespan would increase. The bite mark is shown in the picture:

[image: Kojou's bitemark]

But in later story arcs this seems to be completely ignored. Astarte acts and uses Rhododactylos on her own.

Comment: Eh, by reading this question only, I thought Kojou only put Rhododactylos, *the familiar* under his control, but not herself?